# Visual Studio 2010 crashed, after loading it again it opened the conversion wizard then some bad things happened

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

I was using Visual Studio 2010 and tried to go to a files definition, after about three minutes I found the application had crashed so I end-tasked it. Running the project again I was presented with the conversion wizard (the project was already in 2010 so that was a bit wierd), after going through all its steps it said the conversion had ocmpleted. But I found most of my program directories had vanished and some of the src/include files were not included under the source files/header files sections of the project.

After fixing up all the errors and compiling and running successfully I discovered something new: When it crashed the callstack would not take me to the function but rather the Disassembly of it, but only in some cases.

So for some classes which have a destructor I'm taken to the disassembly location of the destructor even though the function is actually defined and exists, for others it takes me to the source files destructor.

How can I make it so only the source version of the destructor is displayed on the callstack?

Comment: Are you compiling in Debug mode?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I also checked the debug build settings to make sure there was no optimizations going on which would break debugging.